# How to make ASP.NET File Upload control works within ASP.NET Wizard control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am a new .NET developer and I am enhancing an existing legacy ASP.NET Web Forms application where I am trying to use ASP.NET File Upload control within ASP.NET Wizard control. The File Upload control is in an ASP.NET User Control which I am using in different pages across the application. This user control works well in all pages except the current page that includes a Wizard control. I am loading the (File Upload) user control within one of the Wizard steps through OnLoad() method of the wizard. I am currently encountering a strange behavior with the file upload functionality:

Upon selecting a file to upload and click on Upload button the file path will be lost in the OnClick button method. However, if I select the file again and click on Upload button for the second time, the file will be uploaded successfully!!!!!!!!!

Code of asp.net user control that includes the file upload control:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:FileUpload>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="lbtnUpload_Click" Text="Upload">
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lbtnUpload" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code-behind of User Control:

```
protected void lbtnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Check File Prasent or not. Problem: In First OnClick, It will give false
            // After selecting the file for second time and click on Upload button, it will return true!!!!
            if (FileUpload1.HasFiles)   
            {
                //Save uploaded file to the server
            }
        }
```

Code of ASPX page that includes our wizard control where I am dynamically loading the file upload user control in one of the wizard steps:

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled"
    OnLoad="Wizard1_Load">
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" Title="File Upload">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </asp:WizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:Wizard>
```

and here is the code behind of the ASPX page

```
protected void Wizard1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                PlaceHolder PlaceHolder1= wzServiceOrder.FindControl("PlaceHolder1") as PlaceHolder;
                if (PlaceHolder1!= null)
                {
                    Control ucFileUpload = PlaceHolder1.FindControl("ucFileUpload ") as Control;
                    if (ucFileUpload == null)
                    {
                       ucFileUpload = LoadControl("~/Controls/FileUpload.ascx");
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ucFileUpload);
                    }
                }
        }
```

**Any help on how to make the file upload works from the first click on the Upload button?**

Comment: Can I ask why you're using a place holder and not just putting the control right onto the page?